# Is List.assoc an high order function?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I had to make an exercise without using high order functions. Can you explain me what are those?

```
let rec apply asslist elle = 
  match elle with
    [] -> []
  | x::rest -> 
      if List.mem_assoc x asslist then 
        List.assoc x asslist :: apply asslist rest
      else 
        x :: apply asslist rest
```

Did I use any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A higher-order function is a function that operates on functions, i.e., it takes functions as inputs or returns functions as outputs, or both. For example, `List.map` takes a function and applies it to a list, so it is a higher-order function. Contrary, the `List.assoc` function takes a value and a list, so it is not a higher-order function, as it doesn't take any functions. Neither is `List.mem_assoc`, for the same reasons. So your code doesn't use or define any higher-order functions.